# How to run Java Programs

Tags: java

I am just starting Java but I know Scheme...How do you run java code using emacs and putty? I made a program and saved it as first.java on emacs and when i try to open it in putty i did load "first.java" but nothing happened so how do you do this and can yo write Java code in Dr.Scheme?

Comment: If you're used to Dr. Scheme as a learning environment try Dr. Java.

Answer (score 7):

First, you have to name your file the same as the public class that is contained in the file. Then, once your class is written, you need to compile it using `javac` and run the .class file that is produced using the command `java [ClassName]`.

A few things to note is that you are going to make sure you have a Java Development Kit (JDK) and that your path is set up so that javac and java are on the path.

I would poke around the [Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/), specifically the ["Hello World" application example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

To run `Test` class, you need to compile the file and run it.  Here is how you can do it from the command line.

```
javac Test.java
java Test
```

Unfortunately, I cannot comment on using DrScheme (which is a Scheme IDE) for developing Java.  Do you mean that you want to invoke Test class from within Scheme?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't touched Java in years, but [Sun's Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) is probably all you'll need:

Answer (score 0):

Others have already said to make sure your class name matches the java source file name and to run javac on that, and then java on the resulting .class file.  Also, make sure your [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) is properly set when you compile and run.